# Pysal: how to do cross validation with pysal regression models?

Tags: python, pysal

I am using `pysal` to to spatial regression. This what I am doing. I first divided training and validation sets

```
import pysal as ps
m_train = ps.model.spreg.GM_Lag(ytrain, xtrain, w=w_train, spat_diag=True)
```

How can I use the coefficients of `m_train` to do test the model on the validation set?

```
print(m_train.summary)

REGRESSION
----------
SUMMARY OF OUTPUT: SPATIAL TWO STAGE LEAST SQUARES
--------------------------------------------------
Data set            :     unknown
Weights matrix      :     unknown
Dependent Variable  :     dep_var                Number of Observations:         138
Mean dependent var  :      0.2200                Number of Variables   :          12
S.D. dependent var  :      2.2411                Degrees of Freedom    :         126
Pseudo R-squared    :      0.6609
Spatial Pseudo R-squared: omitted due to rho outside the boundary (-1, 1).
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            Variable     Coefficient       Std.Error     z-Statistic     Probability
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            CONSTANT      -0.1456487       0.1166442      -1.2486579       0.2117902
               var_1       0.0326638       0.1420966       0.2298707       0.8181922
               var_2      -0.0252494       0.1520906      -0.1660155       0.8681447
               var_3      -0.0899973       0.1598643      -0.5629610       0.5734615
               var_4       0.0720296       0.1980007       0.3637845       0.7160190
               var_5      -0.1850660       0.1932144      -0.9578273       0.3381499
               var_6       0.3282914       0.1482416       2.2145705       0.0267896
               var_7       0.0769414       0.1665854       0.4618738       0.6441718
               var_8       0.0285464       0.1570794       0.1817320       0.8557930
               var_9       0.0427946       0.1613301       0.2652607       0.7908086
              var_10      -0.1375104       0.1636461      -0.8402910       0.4007452
           W_dep_var       1.0880815       0.0960350      11.3300537       0.0000000
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Instrumented: W_dep_var
Instruments: W_var_1, W_var_10, W_var_2, W_var_3, W_var_4, W_var_5, W_var_6,
             W_var_7, W_var_8, W_var_9
Warning: *** WARNING: Estimate for spatial lag coefficient is outside the boundary (-1, 1). ***

DIAGNOSTICS FOR SPATIAL DEPENDENCE
TEST                           MI/DF       VALUE           PROB
Anselin-Kelejian Test             1           9.856          0.0017
================================ END OF REPORT =====================================
```

Comment: Your coefficients should be at m_train.beta

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered the same problem and tried to work around using the following method. I am not entirely sure if it's the right / proper way. I am also very eager to know if there's any better way to approach this.

```
    x = xtest.values
    betas = m_train.betas    # beta coefficients of the spatial lag model
    betasX = betas[:-1]
    betaRho = betas[-1]

    wtArr, ids = wt.full()        # convert pysal weight matrix into an array

    In = np.zeros((wtArr.shape[0], wtArr.shape[0]), float)
    np.fill_diagonal(In, 1)       

    rho = betasRho[0]
    inter = np.subtract(In, rho*wtArr)
    BRho = np.linalg.inv(inter)

    xNew = np.c_[np.ones(wtArr.shape[0]), x]
    xNew = np.asmatrix(xNew)
    predY = BRho.dot(xNew).dot(betasX)
```

After you get your predicted y, you can test its performance using other methods.